# Getting issue in select drop down using Angular.js and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have one issue in my drop down list using Angular.js.Let me to explain the code first.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Lecture Plan :</span>
<!--<input type="text" name="topic" class="form-control" ng-model="plan" id="plan" placeholder="Add Plan No" ng-keypress="clearField('plan');"/>-->
<select class="form-control" id="plan" ng-model="plan" ng-options="sec.name for sec in listPlanData track by sec.value " ng-change="clearField('plan');" > </select>
</div>
```

the following is my controller file code.

```
$scope.listPlanData=[{
        name:'Select Lecture Plan',
        value:'0'
    }
    ];
    $scope.plan=$scope.listPlanData[0];


$http({
                method:'GET',
                url:"php/userplan/getPlanName.php",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).then(function successCallback(response){
                angular.forEach(response.data, function(obj){
                var Session={'name':obj.plan_name , 'value':obj.lp_id};
                    $scope.listPlanData.push(Session);
                });
            },function errorCallback(response) {
            });

});
```

The following function is after user clicked on edit button.

```
$scope.getLecturePlan=function(plan_name){
           //console.log('plan name',plan_name,$scope.plan);
           $scope.listPlanData=null;
            $scope.listPlanData=[{
                name:'Select Lecture Plan',
                value:'0'}];
            $scope.plan=$scope.listPlanData[0];
            $http({
                method:'GET',
                url:"php/userplan/getPlanName.php",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).then(function successCallback(response){
                // console.log('plan ',response);
                angular.forEach(response.data, function(obj){
                var Session={'name':obj.plan_name , 'value':obj.lp_id};
                    $scope.listPlanData.push(Session);
                    if(obj.plan_name==plan_name){
                        $scope.plan.value=obj.lp_id;

                    }
                });
            },function errorCallback(response) {
            });
    }
```

the parameter `plan_name` is taking the plan name from DB.

The following function is my update function.

```
if($scope.buttonName=="Update"){
            console.log("aaaaaaa",$scope.plan.name);
            if($scope.date==null){
            alert('Please select date');
            }else if($scope.plan.value==null || $scope.plan.value=='0' || $scope.plan.name=="Select Lecture Plan"){
            alert('Please add Lecture plan');
            }else if($scope.topic==null){
            alert('Please add topic');
            }else{

            var dataString = "unit_plan_id="+temp_unit_id+"&plan_id="+id+"&date="+$scope.date+"&lession_plan="+$scope.plan.name+"&topic="+$scope.topic;
            //alert("::"+dataString);

            $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",url: "php/userplan/updatePlanData.php" ,data: dataString,cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                var dobj=jQuery.parseJSON(html);
                //alert(dobj.result);
                if(dobj.result == 0)
                {
                    alert(dobj.error);
                }
                else
                {
                    var updatedata={'unit_id':temp_unit_id};

                    $scope.viewPlanData=null;
                    $scope.viewPlanData=[];

                    $http({
                        method:'POST',
                        url:"php/userplan/readPlanData.php",
                        data:updatedata,
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                    }).then(function successCallback(response){
                        console.log('res',response.data);
                        $scope.viewPlanData=response.data;
                        //document.getElementById("unit_list").style.display = "none";
                        //document.getElementById("plan_list").style.display = "block";
                    },function errorCallback(response) {


                    });

                    $scope.date = null;
                    $scope.plan = null;
                    $scope.topic = null;
                    $scope.clearPlanData();
                    alert("Plan updated successfully...");

                }
            } 
            });
```

In the above drop down list i am binding the dynamically from DB.Now i have one `edit` case in this case all selected data are set in this drop down for the further update.Suppose when user clicked on edit button and `LP1` data set in this drop down.if user selected default name`i.e-Select Lecture Plan` and clicked for update it should display the error message but in this case it is taking the previous value `i.e-LP1` always.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you share the ``LP1`` data and is it assigned to ``$scope.listPanData`` and also share the code for ``clearField`` function...

Comment: @SameerK : I have updated my code.clearField function is used just removed the border color.

Comment: Tried the above code in my local setup and works fine. It seems there is a code which is overriding the selected value with previous one.  Can you share the edit and update functions ??

Comment: @SameerK : I added the code please check my post.

Comment: Asked for update function too . please share update function.

Comment: @SameerK : Please check my post.I added my update function.

Comment: In edit function at line ``$scope.plan=$scope.listPlanData[0];`` , assigning both name and value to scope plan , but in ``successCallBack`` of edit , assigning  only id to scope plan not object (``$scope.plan.value=obj.lp_id;``).  When you update , i guess the value is not available in ``$scope.plan.value``.  So can you just try by assigning full object  like ``$scope.plan=obj;`` instead of ``$scope.plan.value=obj.lp_id;``

Comment: @SameerK : Ok i will check and update you later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96002/discussion-between-subhra-and-sameer-k).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ng-options

```
sec.value as sec.name for sec in listPlanData
```

Comment: I did as per you but it is taking input undefined whatever i am selecting.